# How to use M2Mqtt in Xamarin Forms targeting .Net Standard 2.0 with fallback portability?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, mqtt, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-1.4

I am trying to integrate MQTT in a cross platform app targeting Android as well as Universal Windows Platform (UWP). However am stuck at integrating M2MQTT nuget package.

When I try to install the above nuget package following error is shown even after installing Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility for backward compatibility.

```
Package M2Mqtt 4.3.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package M2Mqtt 4.3.0 supports:
  - net39-cf (.NETFramework,Version=v3.9,Profile=CompactFramework)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netmf42 (.NETMicroFramework,Version=v4.2)
  - netmf43 (.NETMicroFramework,Version=v4.3)
  - win81 (Windows,Version=v8.1)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Sample.UI'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [M2MqttDotnetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2MqttDotnetCore/) v 1.0.8 in a .net Standard 2.0 class library for a xamarin.forms cross platform application.